# UITableView data not appearing in main view using GCD(Grand Central Dispatch)

Tags: ios, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview

i've done all the coding where i fetch data using XML and then show that data on the UITableView, data is shown without using the GCD, but when i add the UIActivityIndicator and used the gcd so the ActivityIndicator will show until the all the data hasn't arrive.

here's my code:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;



    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^ {
        xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc]loadXMLByURL:@"http://www.irabwah.com/mobile/core.php?cat=0"];
        [self.activityIndicator performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
```

in here its returning me zero, means no data arriving, something wrong?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if ([xmlParser listPopulated] == nil) {
        NSLog(@"number of row = %i",[[xmlParser listPopulated]count]);
        return 0;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"number of row = %i",[[xmlParser listPopulated]count]);
        return [[xmlParser listPopulated]count];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the other code that loads the data into data/tableview.  My bet is it's firing before the async method returns so your data is empty when the table view is rendered.

Comment: what exactly do you except, when you stop the activity indicator at the end of the _thread_ that reads the data?

Comment: @bryanmac: what im doing in my project is that getting data from XML and showing it into the TableViewCell, and i dont really get what your saying, kinda confuse here.

Comment: @peko: i think the code where i stop the indicator is in the correct place, coz im parsing the data from that URL and then when the table is populated and all data has arrived im stopping the indicator

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
  dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^ {
        xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc]loadXMLByURL:@"http://www.irabwah.com/mobile/core.php?cat=0"];
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [activityIndicator performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating)];
    });
    });
```

Comment: still doing the same and showing nothing. here's the link of the screen shot http://i178.photobucket.com/albums/w255/ace003_album/ScreenShot2013-08-21at50949PM.png

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly you need to change your data source methods to reflect async loading. For example:

```
- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (xmlParser == nil)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return %NUMBER_OF_ROWS%;
    }
}
```

Then you should reload your tableView after data loading will be completed:

```
    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^ {
        xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc]loadXMLByURL:@"http://www.irabwah.com/mobile/core.php?cat=0"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
```

Comment: plz check the main question again, added data from numberOfRowsInSection